# SonataAdminBundle, sonata_type_collection and embed forms

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Mensaje StackOverflow

Hello everybody!

I'm having a strange issue (cause it was already solved many months ago) regarding SonataAdminBundle. The thing is that my embed forms is not longer working. My approach basically follows this tutorial: http://simonsaysblog.net/sonataadminbundle-doctrine-and-onetomany-relationship (and many other tutorials around the Net).

I have the "User" entity (the one installed by Sonata User Bundle over FOSUserBundle) which has two entities: Email and Phone, in a Many-to-One relationship with User (One user has many email addresses and many phone numbers).

Call the User form display this error message:

> The current field `emails` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``

(The entity name is blank as you can notice).

User.php

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;

/**
*
* @ORM\Table(name="system_user")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
    * @var integer $id
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
    * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="system_user_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @var ArrayCollection emails
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Email", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    */
    protected $emails;

    /**
    * @var ArrayCollection phones
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Phone", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    */
    protected $phones;

    // some other attributes

    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->emails       = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->phones       = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return integer $id
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * Set emails
    *
    * @param $emails
    */
    public function setEmails($emails)
    {
        $this->emails = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $this->addEmails($email);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Get emails
    *
    * @return ArrayCollection
    */
    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }

    /**
    * Add email
    *
    * @param \MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Email $email
    */
    public function addEmails(\MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Email $email)
    {
        $email->setUser($this);

        //$this->emails[] = $email;
        $this->emails->add($email);
    }

    /**
    * Remove email address
    *
    * @param \MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Email $email
    */
    public function removeEmails(\MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Email $email)
    {
        $this->emails->removeElement($email);
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

UserAdmin.php

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

class UserAdmin extends Admin
{
    // some other methods

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('plainPassword', 'text', array(
                    'required' => (!$this->getSubject() || is_null($this->getSubject()->getId()))
                ))
                ->add('emails', 'sonata_type_collection',
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Emails',
                        'by_reference' => false,
                        'cascade_validation' => true
                    ),
                    array(
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'table',
                        'allow_delete' => true
                    )
                )
            // many other fields
        ;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

Email.php

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Email
*
* @ORM\Table(name="email")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MyBundle\Repository\EmailRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Email
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=18, nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
    * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="email_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="emails")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $user;

    // some other attributes

    /**
    * Set user
    *
    * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
    * @return Email
    */
    public function setUser(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get user
    *
    * @return \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

EmailAdmin.php

```php
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

class EmailAdmin extends Admin
{
    // other methods

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('address')
            ->add('notes', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }
    // more methods
}
```

Phone.php

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Phone
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="phone")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MyBundle\Repository\PhoneRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Phone
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=18, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="phone_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;
        /**
     * @var \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="phones")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;
   /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set phoneNumber
     *
     * @param string $phoneNumber
     * @return Phone
     */
    public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phoneNumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    // more methods
}
```

PhoneAdmin.php

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

class PhoneAdmin extends Admin
{
    // other methods

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('phoneNumber')
            ->add('notes', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

admin.xml

```xml
    <service id="myapp.my_bundle.admin.email" class="MyApp\MyBundle\Admin\EmailAdmin">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Configuration" label="Emails" />
        <tag name="security.secure_service" />
        <argument />
        <argument>MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Email</argument>
        <argument>MyAppMyBundle:EmailAdmin</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="myapp.my_bundle.admin.phone" class="MyApp\MyBundle\Admin\PhoneAdmin">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Configuration" label="Phones" />
        <tag name="security.secure_service" />
        <argument />
        <argument>MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Phone</argument>
        <argument>MyAppMyBundle:PhoneAdmin</argument>
    </service>
```

The only one thing I could think it has changed is the location of all the Sonata User files. Before they were locatated into *MyApp\MyBundle*, now they are now into *Application\Sonata\UserAdmin\* folder (as is showed in the Sonata Project documentation).

If I take off the add() method, in the UserAdmin class, corresponding to email, the form renders OK (very slowly, but it renders OK).

Comment: After many research and testing, the best I've could get is to display the Email form embedded into the Sonata User form and the users list. But the only way is by changing the ID of the Sonata User service, from sonata.user.admin.user to a different string. The thing is, if I add the Phone entity (just the property $emails into the User class) the issue gets back. Usually three minutes and a half for a incomplete users list with no CSS format.

I really would like to know what's the deal with the one-to-many relationships in Sonata User Bundle.

Comment: My last try was more weird yet. After modify the User.orm.xml file and defining the relationship with Email and Phone, finally could have a working user list and a form with my two entities embedded, but the next time I try to call the User list the same infinite browser delay come back. Maybe I have to move the User and Group entities to its own application folder? does it makes sense?.

Comment: I found the reason why Email was working with User, but not Phone. In the `user.orm.xml` the property `target-entity` for both fields (emails and phones) was pointing to the same entity: Email.

Comment: ...but the issue doesn't finish there... it gets stranger. Even if I fix the little issue, the behavior persist: almost 4 minutes waiting for an error message that never came out. So, after many experiments I decided to comment those one-to-many tags in `User.orm.xml`, delete the cache and try once again, and it works. The list works and the embedded Email and Phone forms works, but if I logout and login again and call a User form the message: `"The current field 'email' is not linked to an admin` shows up. Uncomment both tags bringing back the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the message, you have to define two other admin classes for your `MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Email` and your `MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Phone` entities (in order to linked them as a `sonata_type_collection` in the `UserAdmin` class).

Comment: You're right! But only in this post :-) because those admin classes do exists in my project. I'm gonna add them right now. Thanks for the remark.